# Struts File upload API abrupt behavior, and file gets corrupted when upload on server through struts API

Tags: struts2

I have web project I which I am using Struts2 framework. In this people uploads the pdf file, for that I have used struts File upload API.

But the strange this, every second file upload is corrupted on server, when I try to open file, it gives me error:

**There was an error opening this document. The file is damaged and could not be repaired.**[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3LChJ.png)

struts.xml

```
<action name="uploadFiles" class="org.webpannel.action.FileHandlingAction"
        method="saveFiles">
        <interceptor-ref name="customeUploadStack" />
        <result name="success">/admin/WindowCloser.jsp</result>
        <result name="input">/service/AttachmentPopup.jsp</result>
    </action>
```

FileHandlingAction:

```
public class FileHandlingAction extends BaseAction implements Preparable{
/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = -470622101009022548L;
private File[] file;
private String[] contentType;
private String[] filename;
private List<String> attachmentsList= new ArrayList<String>();
private String directoryPath;
// the name is written like this, so that no one can easily manipulate.
private String istbamefi;
private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(FileHandlingAction.class);

public void prepare() throws Exception {

    directoryPath = getText("attachments.dirctory")+File.separator+getS3IdFromSession();
    System.out.println("directoryPath::"+directoryPath);
}
@Override
public String execute() throws Exception {
    try{

        File[] filesStored = Utility.listFilesInDirectory(directoryPath);
        if(filesStored==null){
            return SUCCESS;
        }
        for(File fil : filesStored){
            attachmentsList.add(fil.getName());
        }
    }catch(Exception e1){
        logger.error(e1.getMessage(),e1);
    }
    return SUCCESS;
}
public String saveFiles() {
    logger.info("Going to save the Uploaded files");
    if(logger.isDebugEnabled()){
        logger.debug("Directory path :"+directoryPath);
        if(file==null){
            addActionMessage("Please Select a file to upload");
            return INPUT;
        }
        for (File f : file) {
            logger.debug("File :"+f);
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < file.length; i++) {
        try {
            uploadDocument(file[i], filename[i]);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    logger.info("Exiting successfully after saving the files:");
    setMessage("succesfully saved the files");
    return SUCCESS;
}
public String removeFile(){
    logger.debug("Going to delete file:"+istbamefi);

    File file = new File(directoryPath+File.separator+istbamefi);
    if(file.exists()){
        logger.debug("File found");
        file.delete();
        logger.debug("File Deleted");
    }else{
        logger.debug("File Doest not exists");
        setMessage("File Does not exists");
        return SUCCESS;
    }
    setMessage("File Successfully Removed");
    return SUCCESS;
}
private void uploadDocument(File file, String fileName) throws IOException {

    FileInputStream in = null;
    FileOutputStream out = null;
    File dir = new File(directoryPath);
    if (!dir.exists()) {
        dir.mkdir();
    }
     logger.info("Uploaded File Name :" +fileName);
     logger.info("Uploaded File Length :" +file.length());
    String targetPath = dir.getPath() + File.separator + fileName;
    System.out.println("targetPath::"+targetPath);
    File picDestination = new File(targetPath);
     logger.info("Destination Path :"+picDestination);
    try {
        in = new FileInputStream(file);
        out = new FileOutputStream(picDestination);
        int c;

        while ((c = in.read()) != -1) {
            out.write(c);


        }

    } finally {
        if (in != null) {
            in.close();
        }
        if (out != null) {
            out.close();
        }
    }
}
public List<String> getAttachmentsList() {
    return attachmentsList;
}
public void setAttachmentsList(List<String> attachmentsList) {
    this.attachmentsList = attachmentsList;
}
public File[] getFile() {
    return file;
}
public void setFile(File[] file) {
    this.file = file;
}
public String[] getContentType() {
    return contentType;
}
public void setContentType(String[] contentType) {
    this.contentType = contentType;
}
public String[] getFilename() {
    return filename;
}
public void setUpload(File[] file) {
    this.file = file;
}

public void setUploadContentType(String[] contentType) {
    this.contentType = contentType;
}

public void setUploadFileName(String[] filename) {
    this.filename = filename;
}
public void setFilename(String[] filename) {
    this.filename = filename;
}
public String getDirectoryPath() {
    return directoryPath;
}
public void setDirectoryPath(String directoryPath) {
    this.directoryPath = directoryPath;
}
public String getIstbamefi() {
    return istbamefi;
}
public void setIstbamefi(String istbamefi) {
    this.istbamefi = istbamefi;
}

}
```

Comment: Could you check if the PDF has some content, or if it is empty (0Kb) ? In either case, post your code

Comment: Ya PDF file has content . it is 4 MB

Comment: how does your action class `FileHandlingAction` look like?

Comment: For FileHandlingAction  we  have  above code

Comment: Don't read/write file by yourself. Use something like `FileUtils.copyFile`.

Comment: While copying the file from source to destination there may be network issue whole file could not copied. then same issue come here?

Comment: Suppose there  may be   network issue while uploading the file. In this what step we have to fallow in java code to resolve the issue. Is there not any other approach to resolve this issue.